# Request to add a "privacy" tag

Tags: support, tags

I came across this question - [What plans are there to implement privacy on Stellar?](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/463/what-plans-are-there-to-implement-privacy-on-stellar) and felt that it was lacking a [privacy](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/privacy) tag. Since I can't (< 150 rep) add tags, I'm requesting it here ([create tags](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags)).

I'd posted a comment on the question, [as per the guidelines](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags), but that didn't help.